# Error updating Xcode project. Invalid parameter when open XIB from Xamarin.Studio

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xib

I couldn't open any XIB file in project.
Details are below:

- The latest Xamarin.iOS sdk is installed (8.4)
- Xamarin Studio (stable channel)
- 5.5.3 Build 6 xCode - 6.1

Error Details:

```
System.IO.IOException: Invalid parameter
  at System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime (System.String path, DateTime lastWriteTime) [0x00029] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.10.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-3.10.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:474 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectTypeInfo.GenerateObjcType (System.String directory, System.String[] frameworks) [0x004d1] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.5-branch/fbe3e945/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectTypeInfo.cs:236 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeSyncedType.SyncOut (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeSyncContext context) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.5-branch/fbe3e945/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeSyncedType.cs:82 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeMonitor.UpdateProject (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 allItems, MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeIntegration.XcodeProject emptyProject) [0x00417] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.5-branch/fbe3e945/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeMonitor.cs:164 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateXcodeProject (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00050] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.5-branch/fbe3e945/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:517
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/52292/#Comment_52292)one workaround helped me.
Go to ~/Library/Caches and remove all XamarinStudio-XX folders

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in 5.5.4 due out early next week. The work around mentioned above is one possible solution.

Comment: I have 5.5.4 version and it bug appeared for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but without message "Invalid parameter".
In my case problem was that I accidentally included DS_Store to the csproj. I fixed issue opening csproj with text editor and removing all rows connected to including DS_Store to the project

try to delete code similar to this from *.csproj file:

```
<ImageAsset Include="Resources\Images.xcassets\.DS_Store">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
```